# Foundation - Understanding why commenting out doesnt work

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I've just started using Foundation.

I'm currently looking at customising the input fields and have noticed something I dont understand.

For things like the input transition:

```
$input-transition: box-shadow 0.5s, border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
```

If i simply comment it out it continues to show that transition on my page.
What i have to do in order to remove it is:

```
$input-transition: none !important;
```

Could someone please tell me why this is? Why doesnt commenting it out just stop it being applied, why do i need to add `none` and `!important`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, that you are trying to modify *.scss file and don't compile it using SASS compiler to output CSS file.
If you want to adjust Foundation special classes - read more info of how to use scss compiler: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/sass.html.
Either way, you can modify output *.css file and check if that worked.

More info about file structure here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/sass-files.html

Comment: I'm using Gulp to compile the CSS file and am confident thats working ok. When you saying *.scss - I'm editing `_settings.scss` is the same file you refer to?